# is there a way to access and add to an array list of a class while multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have this class that finds a prime number in a range of numbers but I want to partition the range by the amount of threads I want, to find the prime numbers in each threads range. so I divided the range into sections for each thread to use. only my problem is how can I add those prime numbers back into one single array list.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public Primes findPrimes(int lower, int upper) {
            int d = upper/numThreads;
            for (int i=lower; i<upper; i++) {
                if (i%d==0)
                    threads.add(new Thread(new MyRunnable(d-numThreads,d,primes)));
            } 
            for(Thread t : threads) t.start();
     
            for(Thread t : threads) 
                try {t.join();}
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                
            return this;
        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int numThreads;
        List<Integer> primes = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());  
        private static Object lock = new Object();
        public ArrayList<Thread> threads;
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
           private int lower;
           private int upper;
           List<Integer> prime;
           private static Object lock = new Object();
           public MyRunnable(int lower, int upper, List<Integer> prime) {
              this.lower = lower;
              this.upper = upper;
              this.prime = prime;
          }
      protected synchronized boolean isPrime(int number) { 
        if (number <= 1)
            return false;
        for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) 
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
      public void run() {
        for (int i=lower; i<upper; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)){
               synchronized(lock) {
                prime.add(i); 
               }
            }
        }  
      }
}
```

Here is my output for reference...

student@maverick:~/cse1325/P11/full_credit$ java Primes 1

Sum of the 0 primes between 0 and 1000000 is 0

student@maverick:~/cse1325/P11/full_credit$ java Primes 5

Sum of the 5 primes between 0 and 1000000 is 999,995

student@maverick:~/cse1325/P11/full_credit$

Comment: it looks as though you are already doing that

Comment: this would be easier to work on if you would use `Spliterator`, imo. Then you would not have to deal with any threading and locks yourself

Comment: Haven't you already achieved it? And ```synchronized(lock)``` is not necessary since ```prime``` is from ```Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())```.

Comment: I think I already done it but for some reason its not giving me the correct output.

Comment: What is the problem and what is the question?